# How to refresh my viewpager content

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a zoom in and out in my project and when I zoom in the textviews of my viewpager should change their text size what I have is that the first two pages(current page and the next) are not changing the text size but the next pages are changing their text size;
how can I make my viewpager refresh its components directly so that the zoom in can be seen directly? 
I've tried the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

But that didn't work...

Comment: Hi,can you post the code of your adapter ? These seems like zoom features are only activated when recycling occurs. My guess, the zoom abilities are only set on recycle loop.

Comment: I've removed the code thanks because I've got the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So because when the zoom button was called the viewpager had already placed the first two pages if there's more than one page and the first page if there's only one page so when changing the text size in the textviews it won't take it until calling the adapter once again so what I did is that in the zoom in button I added:

```
       int pos=vp.getCurrentItem();//to get the sposition of the current page
       adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();//this builds my adapter once again
       vp.setAdapter(adapter);    
       vp.setCurrentItem(pos);//to get it to the right position
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to iterate through the pages and set it yourself.  Either that or set an OnPageChangeListener and update it when it comes into the current view.

Comment: no this method won't work for me I think... how can I do it otherwise?

Comment: hey thanks I've already answered the question but can't accept my answer until tomorrow that's why it's not marked as answer. thank you for the help.